# Not able to run the CasperJS scripts after updating

Tags: casperjs, slimerjs

I am facing some weird issue. Before updating SlimerJS and casperJS every script were working fine but since from yesterday i am not able to run the scripts. when i run this below command to run the script

```
sudo xvfb-run -a casperjs test --engine=slimerjs testsuite/testing_part1.js --username=user --password=pwd --url=url_of_the_site
```

every scripts are getting failed

has anybody know what/why this error i am getting?
Currently i am using SlimerJS=SlimerJS 0.9.6 and CasperJS=1.1.0-beta3

Comment: it should work with the command you mentioned. And how you are mentioning URL? could you mention it?

Comment: yeah sure. Earlier i used to enter URL like [128.1.1.0:9090/edit.html] this in terminal. But now it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add http:// to your URL like this:[http://URL](http://%7BURL%7D).It will work